# Artifacts showing after bridging edge loops

Tags: edges

I'm not very experienced with Blender and I just wanted to confirm whether this was a bug or something I should attempt fixing.
What I do is mirror my object and then attempt to bridge edge loops in a hole that I made, as soon as I do that some orange lines on edges (which were not modified) appear in the Object mode.
Is this just a visual glitch or something I need to fix with my model?[image: model of a button with glitch visible]

[image]

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie added

Comment: topology looks fine. looks like the x-ray glitches when n-gons are used but that's a non-issue.